# Pyspark cast StrucType[ArrayType, StructureType] to ArrayType[ArrayType,ArrayType]

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a DF with column 'COL_NAME' contain a StructType in format:

```
StructType[StructType, StructType, ArrayType, ArrayType, StructType, ArrayType, ArrayType]
```

The StructType above returned from UDF. I need to cast it to all ArrayType

```
ArrayType[ArrayType, ArrayType, ArrayType, ArrayType, ArrayType, ArrayType, ArrayType]
```

How to do it. Thank you so much

#### Updated

Example:

```
array need to return :
[[before], [after], [from_tbl], [where_tbl], [to_tbl], [lst_tbl], [dbinfo]]

where before/after is a list
before, after = [[query_type,out,[from],[where]],[query_type,out,[from],[where]]]

where querytype is string, out is string, but from, where is list, not same level

to_tbl = [write_mode, [table_name], table_action]
from_tbl, where_tbl, from, where, table_name, lst_tbl, db_info = [a,b,c]
```

when i define UDF, i have to define return schema, nested array not same level so i can not define valid schema for all

Comment: @mck Help me one more time

Comment: why don't you just modify the UDF to return array instead of struct?

Comment: I want do it,but my array need to return is complex, nested array not same level, i updated example on the post

Comment: List in python allow nested element not same level, multi type. But in pyspark, array must  be same level. I have to use StructType instead of ArrayType